# Nuxt Axios Module read status code

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I'm calling a Rest API that returns at least 2 success status codes .
A normal  200 OK and a 202 Accepted status code.
Both return a Content in the body.
If I execute in postman my calls I might get something like

Status code: 202 Accepted. With Body "Queued" or some other values
[image]
[image]
or

Status code: 200 OK. With Body  "ValueOfSomeToken"
[image]
Making the call with axios in my nuxt app:

```
this.$axios.$get('/Controller/?id=1')
  .then((response)=>{
     if(response=='Queued'){
         //Do something
     }
     else if (response=='Expired'){
       //Do something
     }
     else{
       //Do something
     }
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
  });
```

..works, but I actually would like to get the status code (because 202 has other values for  the body responses)

I have no idea how to read the status codes.

I tried using (response,code) =>... but code is then nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract the `status codes` from the response object in `axios`

if you print the response object (as shown in below image) you can see the all the objects inside the response object. One among them is `status object`

[image]

`response.status` will give you the status code that is sent from the server

```
axios.get("http://localhost:3000/testing").then((response)=>{
    console.log("response ",response);
    if(response.status == 200){
        //do something
    }
    else if(response.status == 202){
        //do something
    }
    else if(response.status == 301){
        //do something
    }
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log("err11 ",err);
})
```

In the server side, you can explicitly send any status code using `res.status()` method, for more details refer [this documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res)

```
app.get('/testing',(req, res)=> {
  res.status(202).send({"res" : "hi"});
});
```

**Update:**

By default, `@nuxtjs/axios` returns `response.data` in the `.then((response))`

The `$axios.onResponse` event will have access to the complete response object.

You need to setup an interceptor to intercept the `$axios.onResponse` event and modify the response object

Under plugin directory create a plugin, `plugin/axios.js`

Update the `plugins` section `plugins : ['~/plugins/axios']`
 in `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default function ({ $axios, redirect }) {
    $axios.onResponse(res=>{
        console.log("onResponse ", res);
        res.data.status = res.status;        
        return res;
    })
}
```

In the `res object` in this interceptor you will have the all the values (as it is shown in my first screenshot). But this `res object` is not returned as it is, only `res.data` is returned to our program.

We can update contents inside `res.data` and then return the `res object` as shown in my program `res.data.status = res.status;` .

Now when `axios` returns `res.data` we will have access to `res.data.status` value in `response` object in the `.then((response))` promise

You can access the status using `response.status` inside `this.$axios`

```
this.$axios.$get("url").then((response) =>{
    console.log("status ",response.status);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("res err ",err);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as I stated, I want to use the NUXT.js axios module.. not axios as separate package. I know that with axios it works. I wonder why it is not working on the axios nuxt module. Even thou with postman I see the correct status sent back.My response only has the string... no data object or status/status text

Comment: @CodeHacker i have updated the answer with details of @nuxtjs/axios module. Let me know if it helps

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for. Works great!

Comment: @divine Thanks for the detailed explanation however I'm not being able to use any of the event handlers (onError, onResponse...). I always get a `$axios.onResponse is not a function` error. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @Anonymous may be its a configuration problem. can you share your code on github?

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You can use non `$`-prefixed functions like `this.$axios.get()` instead of `this.$axios.$get()` to get the full response

```
// Normal usage with axios
let { data } = await $axios.get('...'));

// Fetch Style
let data = await $axios.$get('...');
```

([source](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/helpers#fetch-style-requests))