# Get header response Nuxt Axios

Tags: node.js, axios, nuxt.js

I've problem with nuxt overwrite axios response.
Firstly i have try axios in empty nodejs project to check if resource is available.

```
axios
    .head(
        'https://needtocheckthislink'
    )
    .then(function(response) {
// here code 200
        console.log(response.status);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
// Some errors 403 / 404
        console.log(error.response.status);
    });
```

It's work fine but in nuxt i can't get response.data from my request.
Nuxt provide error code but i can't explain it.

```
// for 403
Error: "Network Error"
    NuxtJS 2

    createError

    handleError

// for 404
Error: "Request failed with status code 404"
    NuxtJS 3

    createError

    settle

    handleLoad
```

How can i work correctly with this request ?

Comment: see this answer till the end . it could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/50176112/4525120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i wasn't sure this solution was on client side : [Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101903/nuxt-axios-module-read-status-code/50176112#50176112)
I have use basic http header request.

```
let client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("GET", "http://testUrl", true);
client.send();
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
      if(client.status === 200){
         console.log("res 200");
      }
      else if(client.status === 404){
         console.log("err 404");
      }
      else if(client.status === 0){
         console.log("forbiden")
      }
      client.abort();
   }
}
```